# How to track file upload progress and get url of uploaded file as well in angular 5

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am working on angular 5 application. In which, I have requirement to upload a image and track progress of upload. I also need to get the response of file upload api. Here is my code:

```
upload(){

      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

      this.uploadImageApi(fd).subscribe(res => {this.apiResponse = res},
                                                      err => console.log(err),
                                                      ()  => this.checkUploadApiResponse(this.apiResponse, window)
                                                     );
     }
```

Check response function :

```
checkUploadApiResponse(response: any, window: Window)
{
    console.log(response);
}
```

Api Function :

```
uploadImageApi(fd: any)
{
    return this.http.post<Response>('url', fd).map(response => response.response);
}
```

Comment: This is covered by the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Answer (score 1):

You can use Progress event to check Upload Status!

```
import {
      HttpEventType,
      HttpClient,
      HttpRequest
    } from '@angular/common/http';

http.request(new HttpRequest(
  'POST',
  URL,
  body, 
  {
    reportProgress: true
  })).subscribe(event => {

  if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
     {
     }
  }

  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
     {
      }
  }

  if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    console.log(event.body);
  }

})
```

Comment: I have tried this out, but its good if you only want to console response. But my problem is not to get the response in a variable. Desired response is in event.body.response.data.upload_url. but not get that response.

Comment: console.log(event.body); this will return the response did you check

Comment: yes, it return the response. But I want to get variable from event.body.response.data.upload_url. But its not working.

Comment: can you share your response data

Comment: This is response of event.body :

Comment: {
 response :
     {
      api_status : 1
      code        : 200,
      data   : {
            upload_url : "http://demo.com/uploads/2018/7/18/1531897447blog4.jpg"
             }.
      message  :  "Image uploaded successfully."
       }
}

Comment: try to console this if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    console.log(data.response.data.upload_url);
  }

Comment: still undefined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176221/discussion-between-tarnjeet-singh-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by **Listening to progress events** as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events)

What you have to dp is writing a service function that returns `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` like this.

```
public uploadFile(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadingFile', file, file.name);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'url', formData, {
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

and inject the service to the component that you use to select and upload the file.

```
public uploadFile(): void {
    if (this.file) {
      this.uploadSubscription = this.uploadServiceService
        .uploadFile(this.file)
        .pipe(map((data) => {
            this.getEventMessage(data, this.file);
          }),
          last())
        .subscribe(() => {

        }, () => {
          // on error
          this.percentage = 0;
        });
    }
  }

private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        this.percentage = 0;  // upload percentage
        break;

      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        this.percentage = percentDone;
        break;

      case HttpEventType.Response:
        this.percentage = 100; // file is uploaded
        if (check the event status in here) {   // event.body 
          // show notifications/toast in here
          return;
        }
    }
  }
```

you can use `percentage` to show the percentage usng a progress bar. And using `event.body` you can get the backend response.

you can write a file upload cancel function like this.

```
public cancelFileUpload(): void {
    if (this.uploadSubscription) {
      this.uploadSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```